# I want to operate the window of the other monitor in remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

When I logged in to a server of the multi-monitor environment from the client of the single monitor in mstsc( remote desktop) environment, I do not understand a method to return an application displayed in the server of the multi-monitor by an assistant monitor to the main monitor.

It is assumed that I cut an editor open with a submonitor with the server of the multi-monitor as an example. 
I cannot operate an editor displayed by a submonitor when I log in in mstsc from the client of the single monitor in this state without, as a matter of course, only a main monitor being displayed. 
If there are methods I pull it to the men monitor or to change an editor displayed in this state by an assistant monitor to a submonitor, I want you to teach it.

Environment： 
The server side(Desktop PC NEC Express5800/S70)： 
It is Windows Vista Enterprise the OS 
A main monitor: 1920x1080 
An assistant monitor: 1024x768

A client-side (notebook PC KOHJINSHA SH8):) 
It is Windows Vista Ultimate or Windows xp Professional the OS 
A monitor: 1024x600

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a second monitor for the laptop hook it up and use the /SPAN switch when running mstsc to tell it to span the session across both monitors.

If not, right click on the app in the task bar, and select move.  Then use the arrow keys to move to app fro the secondary monitor to the primary monitor so that you can then see it.

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Desktop Connection (Terminal Services Client 6.0)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925876)

> Remote Desktop Connection supports high-resolution displays that can be spanned across multiple monitors. However, the total resolution on all monitors must be under 4096 x 2048 pixels. The monitors must have the same resolution. Additionally, the monitors must be aligned side-by-side. 
>   To have the desktop of the remote computer span multiple monitors, type Mstsc /span at a command prompt.
>
> **mstsc.exe /v IPADDRESS /span**